# Android library which works with scoket.io(1.0.4) using node js at server side

Tags: android, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to connect **Gottox** (https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) with socket.io (1.0.4)(http://socket.io/) but unable to connect I think Gottox doesn't work with latest socket.io.

Is there any other Java/Android library that I can use to make socket connections between socket.io and android native application.

I am using node.js at server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java supports the latest socket.io 1.x version. I haven't tried it yet.